# Creating new field in Data Studio

Tags: google-cloud-platform, reporting, dashboard, looker-studio

I am new to looker studio. I want to create report on a bigquery table. But that bigquery table doesn't have any column named, **FILE**. But our looker report table should contain **FILE field**, with null in it. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a field with that expression
[image]